# ошибка invalid convestion from int

Tags: c++

я вызываю функцию класса

```
 glas.Painter(figure.x_pol,figure.y_pol, as[4][4]);
```

а вот сама функция

```
void Painter(int x, int y, int as[4][4])
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<4;i++)
  {
  if (as[i][j]==2) array[x+i][y+j]=as[i][j];
  }
}
```

компилятор выдает ошибку

Comment: и увеличивать нужно правильную переменную : `for(int j=0;j<4;` **j** `++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове это -

```
as[4][4]
```

означает значение соответствующего элемента массива. А у вас параметр объявлен как массив.

Передавайте просто

```
glas.Painter(figure.x_pol,figure.y_pol, as);
```

если, конечно, у вас все объявлено так, как я надеюсь :)